# how to implement infinite scroll masonry

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have used masonry js for showing content on my site.

I want to implement infinite scrolling functionality using this file.

I have see this demo

http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html

but i can't understand how I can implement this demo in my website.

This is my website

http://www.techmodi.com/demo/lookandpin_demo/

I have used these js files,

1) jquery-ui.min.js

2) jquery.masonry.min.js

Please give me solution if anyone have.

Thanks

Comment: what ever you what it is mentioned on that url which you mentioned..?? chek it twice..

Comment: I want infinite scrolling in my site

Comment: Even though it's not a good thing to do, this infinite scrolling, read a little about AJAX techniques. Once you understood it come back here if you have problems implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try's Chrome's (or Firefox) inspector (Ctrl+Shift+J), and click on the network tab. There you can see how infinite scrolling works. You have to divide your pages, the addon will not do that for you.